# Rest Assured response - validating nodes matching the same path

Tags: java, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

In my tests a have a responses like this:

```
{
    "commands": [
        {
            "type": "com.our.identity.patch",
            "value": [
                {
                    "op": "add",
                    "path": "/claims/gTwfQubKEl4r",
                    "value": [
                        "vcvWxlsLKV35"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "op": "add",
                    "path": "/claims/Jmq6zrG7LKoJ",
                    "value": [
                        "iiMQoOWKu2OI"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Where `gTwfQubKEl4r` and `vcvWxlsLKV35` are key - value pair.
The same about `Jmq6zrG7LKoJ` and `iiMQoOWKu2OI` key - value pair.
The response can include many key - value pairs.
I need to be able to validate if some key and value are presented in the response or not.
I use `restassured java` so I know I can use a path like `commands.value.path` to get the key and `commands.value.value` to get the value with these methods I wrote:

```
public String getValueFromResponseBody(Response res, String key){
    return res.body().jsonPath().getString(key);
}
```

```
public void validateParameterValueInResponseBodyEquals(Response res, String param, String expectedValue){
    String value = getValueFromResponseBody(res,param);
    Assert.assertEquals(value,expectedValue);
}
```

Where passed `param` is parameter path inside the response like `commands.value.path`.
But I think this will bring me the first node inside the response body matching the passed path while I need to check against all the nodes inside the response matching that path.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this will bring me the first node inside the response body
> matching the passed path while I need to check against all the nodes
> inside the response matching that path

No, it get all that match. Since `commands` node and `value` node are both array, so it will produce a list of list.

```
List<List<String>> lists = JsonPath.from(res).getList("commands.value.path");
[[/claims/gTwfQubKEl4r, /claims/Jmq6zrG7LKoJ]]

List<String> list = JsonPath.from(res).getList("commands[0].value.path")
[/claims/gTwfQubKEl4r, /claims/Jmq6zrG7LKoJ]

String str = JsonPath.from(res).getString("commands[0].value[0].path");
/claims/gTwfQubKEl4r
```

**Solution:**

To get all the `path` in one query, you just need to make `List<List<String>>` --> `List<String>`. You could try flatMap in stream or use another way.

```
List<List<String>> lists = JsonPath.from(res).getList("commands.value.path");
List<String> flat = lists.stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
flat.forEach(System.out::println);
/claims/gTwfQubKEl4r
/claims/Jmq6zrG7LKoJ
```

One more option:

You can use JsonPath (com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath)

```
List<String> list = JsonPath.read(res, "$..path");
list.forEach(System.out::println);
/claims/gTwfQubKEl4r
/claims/Jmq6zrG7LKoJ
```